# Picard Iteration

Tags: analysis

I have the following question but don't know exactly how to solve it compared to previous examples I've had...

$T(f)(x)= x+ \displaystyle\int^{1/2}_0  f\bigg(\dfrac{x+t}{2}\bigg)dt       $

Let $f_o(x)=0$. Calculate $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$ where $f_n=Tf_{n-1}$

Im not sure what the formula for $f_{n+1}$ would look like. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not to calculate without deriving the general form? E.g. $f_1=x+0=x$, $f_2=x+\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x+t}{2}dt$, etc.

Comment: But what would $f_3$ be?

Comment: first you have to finish the calculation of $f_2$.